# Find Item in ObservableCollection without using a loop

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

Currently i have the following syntax (list is a list containing objects with many different properties (where Title is one of them):

```
for (int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   if(title == list[i].Title)
   {
    //do something
   }
}
```

How can i access the `list[i].Title` without having to loop over my entire collection? Since my list tends to grow large this can impact the performance of my program.

I am having a lot of similar syntax across my program (accessing public properties trough a for loop and by index). But im a sure there must be a better and elegant way of doing this?

The find method does seem to be a option since my list contains objects.

Comment: You could use linq, like  [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) or you could implement your own Dictionary with support for [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)

Comment: A dictionary has very very fast lookup on the key but the key must be unique.  Since title is not unique afraid a loop is required.  Optimize the class to be sure Title get; is not sloppy.  If the object has an internal primary key then override GetHashCode with the key.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I Don't know what do you mean *exactly*, but technially speaking, this is not possible *without* a loop.

May be you mean using a LINQ, like for example:

```
list.Where(x=>x.Title == title)
```

It's worth mentioning that the iteration over is not skipped, but simply wrapped into the LINQ query.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

In other words if you **really** concerned about performance, keep coding the way you already doing. Otherwise choose LINQ for more concise and clear syntax.

Comment: So basically my syntax is fine? I was just wondering about the performance, hence my question.

Comment: It's usually mush faster then LINQ, but as you can see too, it's much more code lines, LINQ is much more consise in its writing.

Comment: Okay thanks, guess i will remain with my for statements since performance is really important in my program.

Comment: @Tigran Using LINQ instead of for loop will not decrease performance in any noticeable way (not even with speed tests).

Comment: @YoryeNathan: it depends on situation, in this concrete code example, may be. Usually LINQ is a slower.

Comment: I did not know LINQ was slower +1.

Comment: @Blam: LINQ is not a "magic" but language construct over already available stuff, so by definition it will be slower. The thing is that it brings a lot of benefits too, so to choose it or not is a matter of specific case. In 90% cases you will choose it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm the down voter :( I'm down voting because the OP asks about performance not convenience

Comment: @used2could: I will edit the post, to fit the correct answer.

Comment: @used2could Question also asks about form. "But im a sure there must be a better and elegant way of doing this?"

Comment: For large list performance I will go with a Dictionary whenever possible.   For readability I take LINQ every time and for things like sort it is mush more code without LINQ.

Answer (score 43):

Here comes Linq:

```
var listItem = list.Single(i => i.Title == title);
```

It throws an exception if there's no item matching the predicate. Alternatively, there's `SingleOrDefault`.

If you want a collection of items matching the title, there's:

```
var listItems = list.Where(i => i.Title ==  title);
```

Comment: This is the answer for anyone looking to find one object that meets a specific criteria.

Comment: The question is about performance though and you haven't made any reference to performance. Is it nLogN?

Answer (score 7):

i had to use it for a condition add if you don't need the index

```
using System.Linq;
```

use

```
if(list.Any(x => x.Title == title){
// do something here
}
```

this will tell you if any variable satisfies your given condition.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest storing these in a Hashtable. You can then access an item in the collection using the key, it's a much more efficient lookup.

```
var myObjects = new Hashtable();
myObjects.Add(yourObject.Title, yourObject);
...
var myRetrievedObject = myObjects["TargetTitle"];
```

Comment: You could also consider using a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Answer (score 4):

Consider creating an index. A dictionary can do the trick. If you need the list semantics, subclass and keep the index as a private member...

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a hash based collection (like a Dictionary or Hashset) which the ObservableCollection is not. The best solution might be to derive from a hash based collection and implement INotifyCollectionChanged which will give you the same behavior as an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2):

ObservableCollection is a list so if you don't know the element position you have to look at each element until you find the expected one.

Possible optimization
If your elements are sorted use a binary search to improve performances otherwise use a Dictionary as index.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have N objects and you need to get the Title of all of them you have to use a loop. If you only need the title and you really want to improve this, maybe you can make a separated array containing only the title, this would improve the performance.
You need to define the amount of memory available and the amount of objects that you can handle before saying this can damage the performance, and in any case the solution would be changing the design of the program not the algorithm.

Comment: I would have said using a binary tree over a list is changing the algorithm not the design of the program

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this approach would solve the problem:

```
int result = obsCollection.IndexOf(title);
```

IndexOf(T)
Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire Collection.

(Inherited from Collection)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods

Comment: "The Collection<T> is searched forward starting at the first element and ending at the last element." - so not a valid answer

Answer (score -2):

An observablecollection can be a List

```
{
    BuchungsSatz item = BuchungsListe.ToList.Find(x => x.BuchungsAuftragId == DGBuchungenAuftrag.CurrentItem.Id);
}
```

Comment: "This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count." - not a valid answer